# Unable to resolve target 'android-8'

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

Long story short, eclipse updated ADT & SDK to v20 , which I didn't like and wanted to get back to 18.

So I uninstalled ADT and SKD and donwloaded v18 from

http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r18-windows.exe

and http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-18.0.0.zip

Installed both of them, yet now Eclipse can't seem to find some sdk platform and throws the "Unable to resolve target 'android-8'" error... any ideas what might be wrong?

[image]

Comment: if you update to v20 again, you still will getting this error?

Comment: don't want to update to v20 :)

Comment: only to test ^^, later you back to v18

Comment: updated, but seems the same error.

Comment: please back to v18 "if you want" and enter in this folder /your-android-sdk-path/add-ons/ and see if you already have api8 folder

Comment: no, the folder is empty.

Comment: empty? don't you have any api installed? try install other without the api 8 please

Comment: hmm, probably the SKD 18 ( link above ) seems to come without API 8... do I downlaod it from somewhere manually?

Comment: maybe some add-on sites should be added to the SDK manager?...

Comment: no, the best way is to download this screen. if you can download another api but 8 not maybe the problem is in the server itself that this api be, what I find most difficult is not impossible.

Comment: you can add third addons, like the sdk from motorola and samsung, but it's no solve the problem.

Comment: no on the download screen there isn't anything much for the API8, so I guess I should have somehow added the addon from google for that api?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in android sdk window go to:

tools >> options

will be open a new window and check the option force https:// ....

disable this checkbox

if your network is using proxy conigure it in this window too.

reload or restart the android sdk window and try download again. :)

Answer (score 7):

1. Right click on project->properties.
2. Select Android on left panel.
3. If you see Android 4.0.3 in (Project Build Target), then tick it and click Apply button.
4. If you don't have 4.0.3 version in Build Targets, then you should install it. to install simply go to sdk manager and click on Android 4.0.3(API 15)-SDK Platform.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open "Android SDK Manager"
2. Go to Menu: "Tools -> Options..."
3. Press the button "Clear Cache"
4. Press the button "Close"
5. Close "Android SDK Manager" (not necessary!)
6. In Eclipse, go to Menu: "Project -> Clean..." to refresh current project

Answer (score -2):

simple set your project's target sdk as shown in below screen shot

[image: click here for screen shot]

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. It might be difficult foe the user to get from the screenshot.