# android: requires previous sdk support even if min sdk version is higher?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt, android-sdk-tools

I am new to Android Development and I tried to import an Android Application in to my Eclipse (ADT).
But , I am getting an error saying :

```
 Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
```

But , I checked in the manifest file that , the min sdk and target sdk are set as follows:

```
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Then , why am I having an this error? Why do I require API 8 , even-though the application supports min sdk 11 ? The Application has Facebook and GCM integrated into it?
Is it because of this? Or , are there any classes that require API 8 support?
I am getting confused and not able to find a satisfactory answer.
Thanks.

Comment: check this link , hope it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053353/unable-to-resolve-target-android-8

Comment: no , this link does not help me. I have a higher level APIs downloaded and all those APIs that my minSDk and target SDK have mentioned. Why is it asking me to download a lower level API ? API 8 is nowhere  in the picture of my application.

Comment: check  if u have this jar file annotations.jar in android-sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar

Comment: if not try this , copy 

..\android-sdk\extras\android\support\annotations\android-support-annotations.jar 
and copy it to ..\android-sdk\tools\support\

Comment: I do have Annotations.jar in the specified folder

Answer (score 0):

You application has set Android 8 as target version. Change it from properties option

Right click the project and click "Properties". 
Then select "Android" from  left. You can then select the target version from right side.

Always try to select the highest available target version. Currently go for Android 19 (4.4.2 Kitkat).

Answer (score 0):

`annotations.ja‌​r` is a 2kb file try to download online if not

copy `..\android-sdk\extras\android\support\annotations\android-support-annotations.ja‌​r` and copy it to `..\android-sdk\tools\support\`

Comment: Does your SDK manager show that Android API level 8 is installed?

Answer (score 0):

you have to open up SDK manager and simply installed API level 8.

Comment: I know that will solve the problem , my question is WHY? do I have that problem? why if my minsdk version is 11 and target version is 19 ?